# In a Hausdorff door space, at most one point is a limit point

Tags: general-topology

I'm having some trouble proving the following:

> If $(X,\tau)$ is a Hausdorff door space, then at most one point $x \in X$ is a limit point of $X$.

My approach was the following:

I assumed that there existed $y \in X$ such that $y$ is also a limit point of $X$, and then prove by contradiction that if $x$ is already a limit point, then the point $y$ cannot exist. However, I'm having some trouble completing this proof. Is this the correct approach? Any tip on how to solve this?

Comment: what is a door space?

Comment: A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be a door space if every subset $S$ of $(X,\tau)$ is either open or closed (or both) @Cronus

Comment: Hope you don't mind.  I have edited your title so it is more concise and we can use it as a reference when adding the door property to https://topology.pi-base.org/properties. (does not detract anything from your question, as the text itself spells out the theorem again)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are two distinct limit points. Let $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ be separating disjoint open sets for $x$ and $y$. Then $(U-\{x\})\cup \{y\}$ is not open because it contains $y$ but no other points of $V$, and it is not closed because its closure contains $x$. This contradicts the fact that $X$ is a door space.

Comment: You said that "$(U - \{x\}) \cup \{y\}$ is not open because it contains $y$ but no other points of $V$". Why does that imply that "$(U - \{x\}) \cup \{y\}$ is not open"?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães If it were open, there would be an open set $A$ with $y\in A$ and $A\subset (U-\{x\})\cup \{y\}$. The set $\{y\}$ is not open because every open set containing $y$ contains another point, and hence $A\cap V$ contains $y$ and some other point of $V$. There is therefore no such $A$, so the set can't be open.

Comment: How can you conclude that if $(U - \{x\}) \cup \{y\}$ were open, then it would exist a open set $A$ such that $y \in A$ and $A \subset (U - \{x\}) \cup \{y\}$?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Well you could even take $A=(U-\{x\})\cup\{y\}$, then $A\cap V$ is nonempty and open and contains $y$ hence it contains an additional point of $V$.

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães We showed $A=U-\{x\}\cup\{y\}$ is open, and it contains $y$. This means it must contain some other point from $V$, or else $A\cap V=\{y\}$, and this would mean $\{y\}$ is open, and hence not a limit point, which contradicts our assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

To complement Matt Samuel's answer, the following seems an interesting corollary to state.

> Every Hausdorff [door space](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000126) is scattered.

where a space $X$ is [scattered](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000051) if every nonempty set $A\subseteq X$ has a point isolated in $A$.

*Proof:* If $A$ is a singleton, it has an isolated point.  And if $|A|\ge 2$, by the main result $A$ contains at least one point isolated in $X$.  That point is also isolated in $A$.